# Creating a banner header with 3 images using Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css

I am attempting to make a header for a page I'm designing for a university project.

I've been playing around with different bits of code, and the best that I can manage is 3 images, one below another.  I cannot, for the life of me, see how I can make them next to each other, in a banner, that will then fit the length of the screen.

Header Code:

```
    <header>
      <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="span4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.ibb.co/7vJj2z4/logo-small.png" alt="img">
        </div>
        </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                 <div class="span4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.ibb.co/Mf8HmH7/Jedi-Mind-Reader-Logo-Small.png" alt="img">
        </div>
             </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="span4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.ibb.co/7vJj2z4/logo-small.png" alt="img">
        </div>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
```

Styling Code

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Orbitron, sans-serif;
}

.header, .footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;

}

.footer {
   color: white;
}

.header {
  color: yellow;
}

.header, .footer a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header, .footer a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header, .footer a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: yellow;
}

.header, .footer a.active {
  background-color: black;
  color: black;
}

.header-right, .footer-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header, .footer a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .header-right, .footer-right {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume, either you haven't included Bootstrap (CSS) correctly in your file, or your viewport is too small (forcing the container-fluid col-* elements to wrap around).
Make sure to either include a local copy of Bootstrap, or use a CDN:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: Another thing: I'm not sure whether you were trying to style your `<header>` using `.header` in your CSS. If that's so, it won't work like this. `.header` in this case is the class-name, not the tag's name. Use `header` instead, or add the class to your header: `<header class="header">` to make this work.

Comment: Yes...  I am using Bootstrap:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to apply styles to a class that doesn't exist. You can call just `header {}` but if you use `.header {}` then you need to change `<header>` => `<header class="header">`